# Calculated value getting previous input value using reactjs setState callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning reactjs by creating a simple calculator that doubles a given number. When the callback to this.setState is called it has the existing value of this.state.amount and not the new value that was just entered.

```
  handleAmountChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({amount: event.target.value}, this.calculate());
  },
  calculate: function() {
      this.setState({calculatedAmount: this.state.amount * 2});
  }
```

What should be I be doing to get the most up to date version for this.state.amount in the calculate function?

https://plnkr.co/edit/FoTEK9PglqhUajq1lLXJ?p=preview

Comment: <button onClick={() => {
                    console.log('callingsetState');this.setState((prevState) => ({count: prevState.count + 1}))}} >Increase</button>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30783011/3678689). In short, `setState` only creates a pending state transition, not an immediate state mutation.

In your case, I think the cleanest approach would be to use `refs` instead of passing the value of the input to the state and reading from it:

```
var Calculator = React.createClass({  
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      calculatedAmount: 0.0
    };
  },

  calculate: function() {
    this.setState({calculatedAmount: this.refs.myNumber.value * 2});
  },

  render: function(){
    return (
      <div id="calculator">
        <h3>Calculator</h3>
        <input type="text" ref="myNumber" onChange={this.calculate} />
        <span>{this.state.calculatedAmount}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

**EDIT:** I realized your solution with using a callback is a perfectly valid one but it is not working because you are executing the callback function, instead of passing it. This will do the trick:

```
handleAmountChange: function(event) {
  this.setState({amount: event.target.value}, this.calculate);
},
calculate: function() {
  this.setState({calculatedAmount: this.state.amount * 2});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems a much better way to do things. I am still not sure why the setState callback seemed to be called before the state was transitioned though.

Comment: You're welcome! The difference is between passing `this.calculate()` and `this.calculate`

Comment: Silly mistake by me but I've learnt more about react in doing so. Thanks.

Comment: @JanKlimo why does this.calculate work and this.calculate() does not ?

Comment: You need to pass a reference to the function - without the brackets. If you include the brackets, you would be passing the return value of that function instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, you can set more than one states at once, i.e. execute the calculation in handleAmountChange.

```
var Calculator = React.createClass({  
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      amount: 0.0,
      calculatedAmount: 0.0
    };
  },
  handleAmountChange: function(e) {
    var input = e.target.value; 
    this.setState({amount: input, calculatedAmount: input * 2});
  },
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div id="calculator">
        <h3>Calculator</h3>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.amount} onChange={this.handleAmountChange} />
          <span>{this.state.calculatedAmount}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Calculator />, document.getElementById('container'
```

));